# Would a wise person avoide situations where other could perform lot of demerits?

Tags: daily-life, merit

Would a wise person avoide situations where other could perform lot of demerits?

Or different asked: Would a wise person go out only if meritorious reactions are suspected?

What do you think, or know about the Buddhas view on such?

*(Note that this has been not asked for trade, stacks, exchange or entertainment that binds here in this world, but as means of release)*

Comment: What you mean by `if meritorious reactions are suspected`

Comment: On touch one might probably act kusala. If a wise approaches un-faithful devoted worldlings, akusala, such as upvoting this question, just for example, might be performed by fools, so causing them much demerits. If no touch, they might not conduct such, at least not being touched by good. That is the meaning, Upasaka @follower.

Answer (score 1):

The general Buddhist advise is to associate wise people. There are many Buddhist stories that Buddha encountering unwise people. It appears that Buddha did not have much time for those people. You find stories such as Angulimala. But they appeared to be intelligent people.

Comment: Does Upasaka think that such answeres the question? (It was not about association, btw., althout that is of course right) Do wise leave their good association, to get (in) touch with unwise, even fools, risking that they make again some demerits?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Wise person would avoid situations which can give negative vibrations.
When you are in contact with negative things, they weaken you.
So as much as possible, you should be with positive thinkers.
Because, after all, our life is result of our sankalps, therefore, be with the things which give you hope and confidence.

Comment: With wise he was meant someone who would be no more shaken by the worldily dhammas, householder Manak.

Answer (score 0):

**Would a wise person go out only if meritorious reactions are suspected?**

The [Gilana Sutta (AN 3.22)](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.022.than.html) might imply that a wise person would go out if a meritorious reaction is even possible -- even if an unmeritorious reaction were also possible -- i.e. "on the chance that they may actually turn out to need and benefit from such".

Another way to say it is, perhaps you shouldn't only judge an act by its effect -- "was it effective, successful?" -- but by intent.

Comment: Sadhu and: never on assumed effect, sticking to precepts fist till own intention has been learned to trace rightly. `And it is because there is this sort of person that the other sorts of persons are to be taught the Dhamma as well [on the chance that they may actually turn out to need and benefit from the teaching].`